# Issue with navigating to a new page in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, navigation

I am encountering an issue while attempting to navigate to a different page using the `router.push` function in Next.js.

Specifically, I am trying to use a variable named `ChangePage` to route to another page called "example.js" which consists of a single div element.

However, despite implementing the code, the desired navigation does not occur.

Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
'use client'
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter, usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import Image from "next/image";
import kittycoin from "../../public/kittycoin.png";
import kittyswap from "../../public/kittyswap.png";

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    router.push("/swap");
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <button
        type="button"
        className={`h-14 w-48 px-4 py-2 border border-transparent font-bold text-xl text-center rounded-2xl text-[#f1f1f1] bg-[#320000] hover:bg-[#230100] focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-orange-600 focus:ring-opacity-50 transition ease-in-out duration-200`}
        onClick={handleButtonClick}
      >
        Swap Tokens
      </button>

      <div className="w-[300px]">
        <Image src={kittyswap} alt="Hero Image" width={600} height={600} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have already imported the necessary modules and defined the router variable using the `useRouter` hook. The button component is intended to trigger the navigation using the `router.push` function with the desired page path. However, when the button is clicked, no navigation occurs.

I would appreciate any guidance or insights on what might be causing this issue and how I can successfully navigate to the "example.js" page using `router.push`.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Can you show your files structure?

Comment: .dex/
       .build/contracts
       .contracts/
       .migrations/
       .node_modules/
       .public/
       .src/app/swap.js
                     page.js
                     layout.js
       ./components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a `/swap`  route, you need to create a `swap` folder inside `app`, inside which you add a `page.js` file, which will contain the content of your current `swap.js` file (leading to `app/swap/page.js`).

That's because while with the initial [`pages`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, a file creates a route, since Next.js `v13`, and when using the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, a route is created by a folder and a `page.js` is used to render that route, as the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes) shows it:

[image]

Here is (see the last question) where the CLI asks you which one of the routers you want to use:

[image]

Finally, if you are following along a tutorial and want to use the `pages` router, the easiest way is to create a new project and answer the CLI accordingly:

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```