# Problem with adding a new page in Next.js with the app router

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm setting up a new Next.js 13 project with the following folder structure:

```
- app
  - blog
    - page.jsx
```

I also have another page in the `blog` directory called `test.jsx`. However, when I try to access it using "localhost:3000/blog/test" or any other component name, I receive a 404 error.

How can I correctly reach the `test.jsx` page in my Next.js project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Taha1! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Answer (score 0):

With the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) directory (router), to have a `/blog/test`  route, you need to create a `test` folder inside `blog`, inside which you add a `page.tsx` file, which will contain the content of your current `test.tsx` file (leading to `app/blog/test/page.tsx`).

For a more detailed answer, checkout this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431508/issue-with-navigating-to-a-new-page-in-next-js).